# Superfish Menu Not Loading

Tags: jquery, css

Im currently trying to integrate a superfish menu into my wordpress theme, however it seems to be disappearing. I believe i have coded the js and the css correctly... can someone give me a pointer as to whats up? Or how to integrate into the functions.php

***FURTHER UPDATE****

Ok.... so i put the functions back into my header.php as below:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title><?php bloginfo('name'); ?> <?php if ( is_single() ) { ?> &raquo; Blog Archive <?php } ?> <?php wp_title(); ?></title>
<meta name="keywords" content="Holiday, free CSS template, clean, neat, aqua, white, templatemo" />
<meta name="description" content="Holiday is a clean and neat free CSS template using aqua and white colors." />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>" type="text/css" />
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js">     </script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<?php function my_theme_scripts() {
wp_register_script( 'jquery' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'superfish', 'js/superfish.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
}    
add_action('init', 'my_theme_scripts');
?>

<script> 

$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("ul.sf-menu").superfish(); 
}); 
</script>

<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_class' => 'sf-menu', ) ); ?>
```

Comment: BTW please note that the superfish.css is being called in my style.css via a @import rule... but it is there....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to take a look at the [wp_enqueue_script()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) documentation and modify your code to follow standard WordPress practice. Then look at your output and verify that your JS is being loaded.

Comment: Hi Stephen, i take it that the enqueue script goes in the functions file?

Comment: Yes, `wp_enqueue_script()` calls belong in `functions.php`, inside a callback hooked into an appropriate action hook. But more importantly, your actual script does not account for **jQuery no-conflict mode**, which WordPress enforces.

Comment: See Chip's comment above.

Comment: Hi Chip, Thanks for this... so for example if im calling this JS script.... Will it be like this for example                  <?php
function my_scripts_method() {
 wp_enqueue_script(
  'custom-script',
  get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom_script.js',
  array('jquery')
 );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method');
?>

Comment: Hi guys, can you check out the above and see if i have written that right?

Comment: Yep, that looks about right. :)

Comment: awesomeness :) thanks so much Chip :) and Stephen :)

Comment: HI guys. It still doesnt appear to be loading :S..... im at a loss :S

Comment: Are you actually looking at the page source in your browser? Double check your path and file permissions.

Comment: Hi Stephen, I did right click and view source....... and this is what i have

Comment: Looking at this it aint loading the JS.... 0_o... i did paste this in the functions file

Comment: If it's not loading then more than likely it's a path or permissions issue.

Comment: Permissions?.... well the folder is in a js/superfish.js... is it the fact i need to put the <?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?> to call it inside the Theme Folder?.... Im lost as for the permissions as its on a local host... so im not sure what permissions i need, as i didnt think that would be a problem :S

Comment: Your custom css should be inside your theme directory tree. ../wp-content/themes/_theme_folder_/. The bloginfo('stylesheet_url') is where the style.css of the currently active theme is. So you place it within that directory.

Comment: Hi Stephen, I know that when i put the style.css without the bloginfo bit it doesnt work, it just calls it to the beginning and not actually into the root theme folder...... however the superfish.css obviously i want to call this separate... would it be easier to just stick this style in my style.css?

Comment: I wouldn't suggest that. Makes it harder to maintain.

Comment: thats what i thought.... but i aint got a clue why it isnt loading :S

Comment: Without direct access to your site/machine afraid there isn't much more I can do to help you out. Sorry.

Comment: ok no worries thx

Answer (score 1):

You're also going to run into trouble due to this line in `header.php`:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js">     </script>
```

You're loading an old version of jQuery, and then enqueueing the core-bundled version of jQuery. So, you've got two, probably incompatible, jQuery libraries loaded at the same time.

Get rid of the hard-coded jQuery script link, and just use the core-bundled version that you enqueue.

Comment: oh right ok...... i will try that... is it because its trying to load two different types of jquery?

Comment: well i removed that and and it stopped loading the js altogether, even thou its in the functions file :S

Comment: Do you have a **live link** to the rendered output?